# Computational time increases every loop when training network across varying files

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I have a folder with 100 data sets which I'm looping across in Python; and calling a function definition upon for each data set - which contains my calls to sklearn GradientDescent, trains, fits, predicts, prints results, etc.

I would expect that when the definition returns, and the loop iterates to the next file, all the train/test split, training, etc would be lost however it appears something strange happens in the background as every successive call appears to compound in computational time.

*The first file maybe takes all of 1 second to train while the 100th takes almost 15 minutes; strictly increasing in time as it loops through files which are all similar in nature.*

**Is there a way to completely reset Sklearn when it enters the function defintion? It appears there is some sort of missing garbage cleanup going on....**

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I'll try to clean all it up, it's company stuff so need to get rid of bunch of noise and confidentiality.

Comment: my point is: it should not happen. Most likely, some part of the code iterates over all previous datasets or something like that.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try including `sklearn.base.clone()` into your loop and testing for a performance change. 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.clone.html